# Is it possible to get the absolute request url without path parameters

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to get the request url without values of path parameters into it.

Consider my complete url is

```
URl: http://localhost:8080/aaa/mock/abcd/1234/true
Path parameters: abcd, true
Output needed: /aaa/mock/abcd
```

My web service method looks like this.

```
@Path(value = "/aaa/mock")
@Component
public class MockService
{
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MockService.class);


    //address
    @GET
    @Path(value = "/{mockrequest}/{status}")
    @Produces(MediaType.JSON)
    public String mockEngagement(@Context ContainerRequestContext request,@PathParam("mockrequest") String mockrequest,@PathParam("status") String status )
    {
        log.info("The mock url is"+request.getUriInfo().getRequestUri());  
        log.info("The mock url is"+request.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath()); 
        log.info("The mock url is"+request.getUriInfo().getBaseUri()); 
        log.info("The mock url is"+request.getUriInfo().getMatchedURIs()); 
        **//Out put needed /aaa/mock/abcd**
        return "ajaja";
    }


}
```

None of the above calls return the required info.

I am thinking if there is a generic process to get the desired output irrespective of number of path parameters.

Any such methods.

Answer (score 4):

Try `UriInfo#getPath()`, `UriInfo#getPath(boolean)`, or `UriInfo#getPathSegments()`. The boolean argument is whether the path should be encoded or not.

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.3.1/jersey/index.html

You could also get the absolute path and the base path and then use `URI#relativize(URI)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.getUriInfo().getPathSegments().get(0).getPath()
```

Comment: This is not applicable for `HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score -3):

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {


    Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> o = (Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>)message.entrySet(); 

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> oo : o) { 
        String key = oo.getKey(); 
        Object val = oo.getValue();

        // Thises two properties gives the path of web service 
        //path_to_match_slash
        //org.apache.cxf.request.uri
        if(key.equals("path_to_match_slash"))
        {   String v = (String)val;
            System.out.println (key);
            System.out.println (v);

        }
        if(key.equals("org.apache.cxf.request.uri"))
        {   String v = (String)val;
            System.out.println (key);
            System.out.println (v);
        }

    }
}
```

this code could work only for apache cxf rest 
we can found path_to_match_slash  , org.apache.cxf.request.uri properties in the ContainerRequestContext

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation in plain English for your answer to improve its quality and describe how your code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As much effort obviously has gone into this answer, it might be difficult to get a grasp at if it's just code. It's usual to comment the solution with a few sentences. Please edit your answer and add some explanation.

Comment: On a second glance, it seems obvious to me that this piece of code does not constitute any answer to the question. Especially `"path_to_match_slash"` and `"org.apache.cxf.request.uri"` seem to be complete out of scope here, even if given as example. You've been asked to expand on your answer, but you didn't revise it. In the current state it is not acceptable.